# Save files to OneDrive using PHP same as FTP without show login page

Tags: php, onedrive

I'm wondering if I can use OneDrive for saving integration files between two web apps, so I have to create file and save it to OneDrive on specific folder but this process should be in background using username and password for OneDrive account, so the end user should not see the Microsoft login page or asking them about this app to allow access to his info, (by the way I don't need any information from end user) All what I want is to upload the integration files to specific OneDrive account on specific action exactly same FTP on PHP.

Please any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I used Microsoft OneDrive client on Linux it's name "onedrive-d" you can read more about it from this link: https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by using this client for Microsoft OneDrive on Linux "onedrive-d":

https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old

Wich can help